# Schema Design for Time Series Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-design, time-series

I like to store time-series data in MySQL without opting for other Databases like InfluxDB or Cassandra. In my case how can a schema be in point of both querying and storing data?

In addition to this, I am going to store the data for a year or above but the monthly aggregated data points are sufficient for my application. Can I aggregate the data monthly once and have it in the same table or can we have a separate table for that?

Comment: This should be broken into two or more questions, like "how can I store time-series data in mysql" and "how can I aggregate data based on dates to group it into months?"

Comment: MySQL is fine for time series.  Yes, it can handle reads and writes.  The monthly summaries should be in another table (or a few different tables).  Your question is much too broad to ask on stackoverflow; look around some more.  When you get a more specific question, come back.